# Flash getTimer() not working in Flash Builder 4.5

Tags: flash-builder, flash-cs5, gettime

I've been following some tutorials and they use the function `getTimer()` in the actionscript code, but when I use it, it gives me:  `1180: Call to a possibly undefined method getTimer.`

I'm using Flash Builder 4.5 for PHP and Flash CS5.5.
The settings for my FLA file are set at Player v9 and ActionScript 3.0

I'm calling the funcion in this class:

```
package main.tutorials.ch1
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

public class CollisionTest extends Sprite
{
  ....
    public function CollisionTest()
    {
      .... 

        trace(getTimer());
    }
}
}
```

I don't think it's the imports..
It's probably a missing library in Flash Builder, but I'm new and I don't know where or which library would be missing.
I also changed it to `extends MovieClip` but it still won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling, i found the following:
http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=158893
It says you should add the following import.

```
import flash.utils.getTimer;
```